# Winforms VLC is unable to play any http/https video

Tags: c#, winforms, vlc, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I'm trying to play an HLS on a WinForms application. I've found out that MediaPlayer doesn't support this format, but the VLC lib does. But when I'm trying to stream the HLS with the VLC lib, it doesn't work. I then tested the VLCControler with the Big Buck Bunny video and that didn't work either, only when I play a local video, it works.

The code I'm using to play the Big Buck Bunny video is:

```
mediaPlayer.Play(new Uri("https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4"));
```

And the VLC debug output is:

```
[00eee3b8] main libvlc debug: VLC media player - 3.0.16 Vetinari
[00eee3b8] main libvlc debug: Copyright ┬® 1996-2021 the VideoLAN team
[00eee3b8] main libvlc debug: revision 3.0.16-0-g5e70837d8d
[00eee3b8] main libvlc debug: configured with /home/jenkins/workspace/vlc-release/windows/vlc-release-win32-x86/extras/package/win32/../../../configure  '--enable-update-check' '--enable-lua' '--enable-faad' '--enable-flac' '--enable-theora' '--enable-avcodec' '--enable-merge-ffmpeg' '--enable-dca' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-libass' '--enable-schroedinger' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-live555' '--enable-shout' '--enable-goom' '--enable-sse' '--enable-mmx' '--enable-libcddb' '--enable-zvbi' '--disable-telx' '--enable-nls' '--host=i686-w64-mingw32' '--with-contrib=../contrib/i686-w64-mingw32' '--with-breakpad=https://win.crashes.videolan.org' '--enable-qt' '--enable-skins2' '--enable-dvdread' '--enable-caca' 'host_alias=i686-w64-mingw32' 'CFLAGS= ' 'CXXFLAGS= ' 'PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config' 'PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/i686-w64-mingw32/pkgconfig'
[00eee3b8] main libvlc debug: using multimedia timers as clock source
[00eee3b8] main libvlc debug:  min period: 1 ms, max period: 1000000 ms
[00eee3b8] main libvlc debug: searching plug-in modules
[00eee3b8] main libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\plugins.dat
[00eee3b8] main libvlc debug: recursively browsing `C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins'
[00eee3b8] main libvlc debug: plug-ins loaded: 496 modules
[00eee4f0] main logger debug: looking for logger module matching "any": 2 candidates
[00eee4f0] main logger debug: using logger module "console"
[00eee3b8] main libvlc debug: translation test: code is "en_GB"
[05f18798] main keystore debug: looking for keystore module matching "memory": 3 candidates
[05f18798] main keystore debug: using keystore module "memory"
[00eee3b8] main libvlc debug: CPU has capabilities MMX MMXEXT SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 FPU
[05fb9458] main generic debug: creating audio output
[05fce1c0] main audio output debug: looking for audio output module matching "any": 6 candidates
[05fce1c0] mmdevice audio output error: cannot initialize COM (error 0x80010106)
[05fce1c0] directsound audio output debug: found 5 devices
[05fce1c0] main audio output debug: using audio output module "directsound"
[05fb9458] main generic debug: keeping audio output
[05fdcfc8] main input debug: Creating an input for 'Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4'
[05fdcfc8] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
[05fdcfc8] main input debug: using timeshift path: C:\Users\thor0\AppData\Local\Temp
[05fdcfc8] main input debug: `https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4' gives access `https' demux `any' path `test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4'
[05fcf2a0] main input source debug: creating demux: access='https' demux='any' location='test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4' file='\\test-videos.co.uk\vids\bigbuckbunny\mp4\h264\1080\Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4'
[07eb4c30] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module matching "https": 15 candidates
[07eb4c30] main demux debug: no access_demux modules matched
[07eb8108] main stream debug: creating access: https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4
[07eb8108] main stream debug:  (path: \\test-videos.co.uk\vids\bigbuckbunny\mp4\h264\1080\Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4)
[07eb8108] main stream debug: looking for access module matching "https": 27 candidates
[05fd2e28] main tls client debug: looking for tls client module matching "any": 1 candidates
[05fd2e28] gnutls tls client debug: using GnuTLS version 3.6.15
[05fd2e28] gnutls tls client debug: loaded 125 trusted CAs from system
[05fd2e28] main tls client debug: using tls client module "gnutls"
[05fd2e28] main tls client debug: resolving test-videos.co.uk ...
[05fd2e28] gnutls tls client debug: TLS handshake: Error in the push function.
[05fd2e28] gnutls tls client debug: Winsock error 0
[05fd2e28] gnutls tls client error: TLS handshake error: Error in the push function.
[05fd2e28] main tls client error: TLS session handshake error
[05fd2e28] main tls client error: connection error: Access denied
[05fd2e28] gnutls tls client debug: TLS handshake: Error in the push function.
[05fd2e28] gnutls tls client debug: Winsock error 0
[05fd2e28] gnutls tls client error: TLS handshake error: Error in the push function.
[05fd2e28] main tls client error: TLS session handshake error
[05fd2e28] main tls client error: connection error: Access denied
[07eb8108] access stream error: HTTP connection failure
[07eb8108] main stream debug: no access modules matched
[05fdcfc8] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[05fdcfc8] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4'. Check the log for details.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you play that URL in a browser ? (I cannot, it fails with http status 429)

Comment: @binary01 Yea, I can. But I've just changed the URI to another one, that is smaller and from another source. I still get the same error message, but maybe you can open that as well.

Comment: share full sample repro, this works fine here

Comment: Does it work fine with VLC.exe on the same machine? does it work on another machine? which windows version are you using?